# How to set default console keyboard layout in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, console, tty, keyboard-layout

Whenever I reboot my computer, I have to set the keyboard layout in a console again with `loadkeys`.
Is there a way to change the default keyboard layout that is loaded every time the computer boots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check (my) `/etc/vconsole.conf`:

```
KEYMAP="hu"
```

See [releated wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KEYMAP) for more information!

Comment: First, list all acceptable values with the command `$ localectl list-keymaps`

Answer (score 19):

At least for Arch, you have two types of configuration: via console and Xorg.

The easiest way without configuring Xorg:

```
$ sudo setxkbmap -layout us
```

You can see the current configuration with this:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
$ localectl status
```

To list all the available key maps or layouts:

```
$ localectl list-keymaps
```

Comment: Good, detailed answer. Worked for me without sudo; globally for all already opened apps without logging out.

Answer (score 2):

How to persistently change console layout:
`sudo localectl set-keymap --no-convert us`
The result is the same as directly editing `/etc/vconsole.conf`. To also change the layout for user prompts that run early in boot like for LUKS passwords, rebuild the initramfs with `mkinitcpio -P`

To persistently change layout that's used outside of console, you can use `sudo localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap` but that command is more confusing, so read the second Arch Wiki article linked below before using it.
As an example, here's how to set the dvorak variant of the us keymap to default: `sudo localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap us "" dvorak ""`

Setting console layout: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Persistent_configuration
Setting non-console layout: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_localectl