# Can't write tildes on konsole and certain console emulators

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, terminal-emulator, konsole

So im completely bewildered on this problem, initially two years ago i remember being able to use tildes(~) easily on terminal emulators, but for some reason it suddenly stopped working for this and other small characters on certain terminal emulators(like konsole and kitty but strangely not alacritty where at least for tildes it seems to work).
I would like to provide more data but the only thing that journalctl provides is this which seems to be related to my keyboard somehow:

```
ago 11 21:53:10 micron konsole[57951]: qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table
ago 12 00:05:32 micron yakuake[6053]: qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table
ago 12 00:41:43 micron konsole[230660]: qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table
ago 12 00:42:17 micron konsole[231203]: qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table
xkbcommon: ERROR: couldn't find a Compose file for locale "pt_PT.UTF8"
[224 00:46:09.943101] [glfw error 65544]: Failed to create XKB compose table for locale pt_PT.UTF8
```

I forgot to add but i run two keyboards typically however every time i unplug my external keyboard(im working on a laptop and the embedded one has some few physical keys missing) i run to set my portuguese layout

`setxkbmap pt`

I work on arch linux, and althought its a bit outdated, ive updated it for months, and the problem persisted so not being updated doesnt seem to be the problem.

I kinda suck at writting and will divulge to much so feel free to offer criticism on text i can cut from this question

***Update***: i now know why it stopped working in general, although i don't know precisely how to fix it, apparently konsole when i use kde as the desktop manager instead of openbox makes it work, i've attemted to manually fill out the enviroment variables on .zshrc that are unset
namely these:

```
export LANGUAGE="pt:en"
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="KDE"
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="KDE"
```

ive tried changing this to autostart file on /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart but for some reason both set and export get ignored

Comment: have you set the correct keyboard layout? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75519/how-to-set-default-console-keyboard-layout-in-arch-linux#93040 https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration - from the Archwiki: Use localectl status to view the current keyboard configurations. (it's OK if none is set for X11, then you need to do it in your desktop's preferences)

Comment: `System Locale: LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: pt-latin1
      X11 Layout: pt
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Variant: qwerty `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was fairly stupid.

So regardless of the system locale i had or the the way i set the layout there was an "error" on the environment file on openbox.
To fix it literally just had to go to `/etc/xdg/openbox/environment`
which before i had edited it looks like this

```
#
# Set system-wide environment variables here for Openbox
# User-specific variables should be placed in $HOME/.config/openbox/environment
#

# To set your language for displaying messages and time/date formats, use the following:
LANG=pt_PT.UTF8

# To set your keyboard layout, you need to modify your X config:
# http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+keyboard+layout+xorg
setxkbmap -layout pt
```

The sollution is to literally add a dash making it `pt_PT.UTF-8`. I also removed the -layout flag for no other reason than because im used to it ie to keep consistency and now everything is running smoothly like it should

Im still unaware if somehow in a config file somewhere i messed up, or if autobox has this error by "default"